# How do I invoke credentials stored in Jenkins to deploy to a custom Nexus from within a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I have a custom Nexus for project related utility jars. I have a Jenkins to build these jars.

I want to use gradle in the project and a Jenkinsfile to define the pipeline. As the last stage, I want the build job to deploy the artifact to my Nexus.

Since I don't want the credentials for the Nexus in my source repository (and therefor neither in the gradle script nor in the Jenkinsfile), I set up a credentials entry in the Jenkins Credentials plugin, containing user and password for the Nexus.

**How do I refer to these credentials from within the Jenkinsfile such that I can use them to deploy to the Nexus?**

Currently, my deploy stage looks like this:

```
stage('Publish') {
    sh "gradle upload"
}
```

**Can I use gradle for this purpose at all?** I know I can use it locally, but it would be ok for me to use a different command from within the Jenkinsfile.

In gradle, I use this to define the task:

```
def nexusUser = "$System.env.NEXUS_USER"
def nexusPass = "$System.env.NEXUS_PASS"

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-releases/") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUser, password: nexusPass)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I set the user and password as environment variables locally. That's not an option on the Jenkins, of course.)

Comment: Why is using environment variables not going to work?

Comment: Totally agree you can include environment variables in your jenkins installation.

Comment: You can also use the Global Credentials provided by Jenkins

Comment: @mkobit: Environment variables would certainly work. It does locally, too. I just don't want to put credentials into env vars that are visible for anyone else. But maybe there is a way to solve this with env variables that I don't see and hence my hesitation to use them.
@Carlos: Can you give an example of what you mean with the `Global Credentials provided by Jenkins`? Could you formulated that as an answer?
Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @inedible if you use [withCredentials(){}](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#withcredentials-bind-credentials-to-variables) env vriabels will be visiable only inside its block `{}`

Comment: @Vitalii Thanks for that hint! This looks very much like what I wanted, because it allows me to manage the credentials in Jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set external variables in **~/.gradle/gradle.properties**

`nexusUser=superuser
nexusPass=superpassword`

Comment: Yes I guess that this is the optimal solution, remember that you need to change it under jenkins user (which actually is executing the CI)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [withCredentials(){}](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#withcredentials-bind-credentials-to-variables) step to inject environment variables which will be visible only inside `{}` block.

Comment: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs

Comment: Perhaps you could add a snippet?

Comment: https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/issues/129#issuecomment-402816005